# add on click to a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying hard to understand the syntax of `.on("click"` but just can't get it.

If I have this code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".somediv").not(":contains('$someparam')").addClass("hidden");
    });
</script>
```

What do I have to do for it to display `$someparam` as a link on page, and clicking this link will activate this jQuery to hide the divs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is `$someparam` ?

Comment: You should post the HTML too

Comment: Note that the `:contains` selector only works for text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i understood this question is that to add a hidden css class to the somediv css class which contains specific $someparam at on click.

you can find it in the fiddle:

> **http://jsfiddle.net/DwAAQ/**

here is the `css` i used:

```
    .somediv{
        width:100%; 
        height:20px; 
        margin:0 0 10px 0; 
        border-bottom:solid 1px red;
       }
    .hidden{
       display:none;
      }
```

here is the `html` i used:

```
    <div class='somediv'>1 is</div>
    <div class='somediv'>2 not</div>
    <div class='somediv'>3 not</div>
    <div class='somediv'>4 is</div>

    <button class='someclass'>someClass</button>
```

this is the `jQuery i used with on click` handler:

```
    $(function(){
        var $someparam = 'is';

        $(document).on('click', '.someclass', function() {
            $(".somediv").not(":contains('" + $someparam + "')").addClass("hidden");
        });
    });
```

What this is doing, first of all it has a `variable which contains a specific string` in this case i took `'is'` contained in the divs. So when document gets ready then we have a `button here to click which executes the line in the jquery` to add the `.hidden css class`

Comment: Wow, amazingly that sparked quite a discussion. Thank you guys for your input and especailly for explanations. The code I pasted is a working jquery macro I use to hide the div if it doesn't contain certain divs.

Comment: if this helped you, you can accept it as answer to your question so that others can also see that it helped you.

Comment: I will surely do, I'm in the process of testing.

Comment: Jai, how do I change         $(document).on('click', '.someclass', function() {           to use someparam (that's a string) instead of the .someclass button?

Comment: what is **'someparam'**? and where?

Comment: In your example above, you're setting the variable to "is". Can the same variable be used as clickable text instead of .someclass button in your fiddle?

Comment: I guess I fail at explaining. :( Let's try again. The example you were so kind to provide creates a button, clicking which hides div that contain certain text, set in a variable $someparam, which is great. Can we replace the created button with text (defined by the same variable $someparam), clicking which will do exactly the same - hide the divs that contain the text? I.e., adjusting your example, instead of the button there will be text ( IS ), clicking which will activate the query?

Answer (score 0):

Basically .on is used for something different entirely. You only need the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) mouse event:

```
.click( handler(eventObject) )
```

So for your specific example it would be the following:

```
$('.someclass').click(function() {
    $(".somediv").not(":contains('$someparam')").addClass("hidden");
});
```

(By the way, you might want to check the '$someparam' part - that doesn't really make sense to be in inverted commas).

Comment: Entirely different? Sure `.on` can be used for event delegation if a selector parameter is passed, however `$().click(handler)` is nothing but a shorthand for `$().on('click', handler)`.